# Provider hosted app for Sharepoint 2013 connection to azure website error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, provider-hosted-app, azure

I am creating a basic provider hosted ShatePoint 2013 app where i am just trying to print hello world on the app. Now i tried following steps in the below site.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2013/02/18/building-your-first-provider-hosted-app-for-sharepoint-using-windows-azure-part-1.aspx
on the step where we have to import publishing profile and validate connection there I am getting an error

[image]

ok even if I ignore this and proceed further with the publish then it gives the following error.

[image]

Other resource i tried to follow is:

http://www.looselytyped.net/2012/10/24/build-a-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-5-mins/

But of no use again.

Just wanted to know what is wrong in what I am doing?

Any help would be really appreciated.Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're facing a SharePoint issue since this is happening as you try to publish. Nothing related to SharePoint at this point. You might have more success tagging this with Azure.